# Unity - Get Random Color at Spawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, spawn

i have a little issue....i want to spawn Quads in my Scene and they all should have either red or green as Material. But the Random.Range function will only int´s, how could i solve it ??

```
void SpawningSquadsRnd()
    {
        rndColor[0] = Color.red;
        rndColor[1] = Color.green;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            GameObject quad = Instantiate(squadPrefab, new Vector3(Random.Range(- 23, 23), 1.5f, Random.Range(-23, 23)), Quaternion.identity);
            int index = Random.Range(0, rndColor.Length);

            quad.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = //Random.Range(0, rndColor.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited my answer for getting colors other than Red and Green. You can take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want only red and green you can achieve it with a basic if and else structure like this:

```
    int index = Random.Range(0, 1);
    if(index == 1)
    {
        quad.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(1, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        quad.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0, 1, 0);
    }
```

If you want something better you can random a float between 0 and 1 and then Lerp between colors like this:

```
    float index = Random.Range(0, 1);
    quad.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green, index);
```

If you want to fully randomized the coloring you can also use this as well. However, it gives you limited amount of control over colors you are getting.

```
 quad.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Random.ColorHSV();
```

`ColorHSV` method has several overloads which gives you some control over color like using `hueMin` and `hueMax`.

Another option to have control over colors can be as @Szymon stated having a color array with plenty of colors and randoming an index between 0 and length of that array.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot by anyway the color doesn´t change :( any ideas why?

Comment: I would say i need more information. Are you sure you access the material correctly?

Comment: i think so - gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.x;

Comment: But that line will only work if you are trying to change the color of gameObject to which  the script is attached. I thought you were using `quad.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.x`

Comment: no that Scipt was to Instantiate the Quad but i thougth it would be better to change the color in an extra Quad Scipt after they´re were spawn

Comment: Well if Quad script is attached to quad prefab and has a material on it `gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.x` should work. You can instantiate it from another script it is not a problem.

Comment: ok i have it....something is wrong with the object.....the scipt works fine. Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 2):

In order to get random color please try :

```
var randomColor = rndColor[new Random().Next(0,rndColor.Length)]
```

In that way you will get the random index, and thus the random color from array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Random.Range() method to generate a random number between 0 and 1 and take that value as the color code values for Color class.

Consider this example,

Here I am going to change the color of the ball gameobject with random value.

```
ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(Random.Range(0, 1f),Random.Range(0f, 1f),Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1f);
```